# How to return multiple result sets from a mysql database using a C#.NET Winform application

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, multiple-resultsets

I have a Winform C#.NET application.

When i used SQL Server , then  to return two result sets together, I passed two SELECT queries using a linebreak '\n' , but how to do it in mysql?

IN SQL SERVER i did this and it completed :

```
"SELECT ProductName FROM Products" +"\n" +"SELECT ProductID FROM Products"
```

But how to do this in MySQL????

Comment: is your example a bad example because surely you'd just do "select productName, productID from Products" as a single select.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL this is impossible due to its limitations. Long time ago they've decided that it's unsafe to allow multiple queries in one batch. This was probably because MySQL was often used in conjunction with php and it was common to do simple SQL injection attacks simply by adding semicolon and injecting another query.

PS> I don't know if it applies to new versions of MySQL since something might have changed since I was using it (about 3 years ago).

PS> I would suggest using stored procedures to accomplish this task.

This would probably look sth like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sample_procedure()
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  SELECT xxx FROM yyy;
  SELECT zzz FROM vvv;
END;
```

Comment: I'm not saying that it's totally impossible to return multiple result sets in MySQL. It's impossible to do that this way (at least it used to be). AFAIR php PDO supported multiple result sets and I think I've used that once or twice probably with stored procs.

Comment: sir, can you please help me out with the Stored Procedure code for the example in my above post?

Comment: One more thing (to be sure). Those queries are for demonstration purpose only, right? Because if this is the real problem then the solution is simply `SELECT ProductName, ProductID FROM Products`